# Kill orphan threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I have an API handler function like this:

```
def handler():
    t = Thread(func, args=(args,))
    t.start()
    return {
       'status': 200,
       'data': 'Triggered data collection'
    }
```

It calls the `func` function which does some third party API calls and waits for its data. Something like this:

```
def func():
    resp, content = requests.get(BLABLABLABLA)
    return { 'status': 200, 'resp': content }
```

I have a cancel data collection functionality, which should be able to stop the thread execution of `func()`. The problem is when I kill the PID of `func()`, it waits for it to complete and then gets destroyed. Which can be very long time. Is there any way I can stop the thread right away or the process can kill the thread right away(I read that it is not a good idea but still :|)? BTW, due to some constraints I can't switch to `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread